# Is there a single-word adjective for "having exceptionally strong moral principles"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Yesterday I was writing an English text and found myself unable to find a single-word adjective to characterize a man with very strong moral principles, so I had to reformulate the entire sentence.

I'm curious whether there is such an adjective in the English language at all.

Of course, I know the word "decent," but it sounds like "normal," "good," "not a crook," while I wanted something stronger to convey the idea that he's well above the average in this regard.

But I am not looking for a too pretentious word like "saint." Just a regular word to say that someone has substantially stronger moral principles than the average Joe.

Here are examples of intended usage:

> I was supervised by a _______ professor. He always let me be the first
> author of my articles despite the common practice at the university.

> She wants her daughter to marry an intelligent and ________ man who is
> an XXX party member. But to make her wish physically fulfillable, she
> must remove one of these three requirements.

Comment: Integrity is by definition genuine; it needn't be qualified.

Comment: @Heartspring Thanks, I've edited the title

Comment: One difficulty, beyond the plain word *moral*, is the preachy quality that some "very moral" folks have, like being puritanical (not a compliment).

Comment: If a hyphenated word will do, _high-principled_.

Comment: @KateBunting  I would say *principled* by itself will do.

Comment: I suggest "highly principled."

Comment: Lots of good words here: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/principled

Comment: @YosefBaskin, yes, and that is true of several of the words that have been offered on this page: they are, among the present-day English speakers often used ironically, and to express a subtle criticism of the person's self-righteousness, rather than praise. If one wants to use them as genuine commendations (which is what, taken literally, they are), one has to be very sure that the context and the tone of voice make it clear that this is what is intended. The words for specific moral qualities (e.g. *just, truthful*) are less likely to cause such problems.

Comment: "The adjective **hoity-toity** started out meaning "riotous behavior" in the 1660s. By the late 1800s it had gained its modern meaning, probably out of similarity to the word "haughty.""

Comment: A professor that puts their name last instead of first, when that goes against the social norm, is simply *their own person*.... *principles* : "a *fundamental truth* or proposition that serves as the foundation for a system of belief or behavior or for a chain of reasoning." *morals* : "*a person's* standards of behavior or beliefs concerning what is and is not acceptable *for them* to do." .... When you've got a single word for both *Rudolph the Red-nosed Reindeer* and *homie-don't-play-that* lemme know.

Comment: *their own person* : "Independent in action or thought; not accepting or swayed by outside influences" ... which is as 'moral' as a person can get IMO.

Comment: @rhetorician - Yes, I thought of _highly_ at first, but when I looked it up I found more instances of _high-principled_.

Comment: While the answers below offer several good suggestions, which may work in some contexts, the best way to convey the idea precisely, and minimise the likelihood of misunderstanding, is to not insist on a single word, but instead describe at some length what one has in mind (e.g. *fully committed to her moral principles*).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Principled** or **high-principled** [[M-W]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/principled):

> exhibiting, based on, or characterized by principle.
>
> Example sentences:
>
> - She took a principled stand on funding public education.
> - a high-principled art expert who always told clients what he honestly thought their items were worth
> - [...]Fishback was regarded as a principled officer who staked his future on protecting captors and captives alike[...]

Answer (score 32):

One such word would be *[scrupulous](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=scrupulous&title=21st)*, defined as

> having scruples; being careful to do nothing morally wrong.

Comment: I think "scrupulous" is the best answer. The others (principled, virtuous, righteous, upstanding, etc) fit to some extent, but only scrupulous conveys the extreme nature of being righteous that the OP asked for, whereas the others are more generic and moderate. Rectitudinous might also work but that borders on being too "saintly" or "pretentious"

Comment: Nah. It's true that literally and etymologically, ***scrupulous*** derives from moral scruples. But in practice today it's actually far more likely to be used metaphorically, as per the full OED definition #5 *Minutely exact or careful (**in non-moral matters**); strictly attentive even to the smallest details; **characterized by punctilious exactness**.*

Comment: I agree that scrupulous is taking on a somewhat negative or at least unduly fussy connotation. Of course, that movement itself could be seen as a sign of moral decline in the English-speaking world. Psychologists call a mental disorder where people worry obsessively about their sinfulness "scrupulosity."

Answer (score 26):

You could use [virtuous](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/virtuous)

> having good moral qualities and behaviour:

> He described them as virtuous and hard-working people.

or

[upstanding](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upstanding) (the formal equivalent of @TaliesinMerlin's answer)

> behaving in a good and moral way:

> She is regarded as an upstanding citizen in the local community.

Answer (score 13):

In the contexts you provide, the word **irreproachable** would work well. It is defined [by TfD as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/irreproachable)

> Perfect or blameless in every respect; faultless

Answer (score 11):

How about ***upright***?
Note that this word has been mentioned several times in the definitions of other words.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upright) defines "upright" as follows:

> 1 a: PERPENDICULAR, VERTICAL
> b: erect in carriage or posture
> c: having the main axis or a main part perpendicular
> *upright* freezer
> **2 : marked by strong moral rectitude**
> **an *upright* citizen**

(Boldface mine.)

Comment: ''Upstanding'' would be much better if you want to say it that way ie. ''an upstanding member of the community''.

Comment: @HollisWilliams I don't know about "much better". Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 9):

*Integrity* does have an adjectival form, *integrous.* It is rare, however, and its [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/integrous) definition includes a usage note:

> Integrity is much more common than its adjectival form, integrous. Most speakers and writers opt for an etymologically unrelated synonym — such as honest, decent, or virtuous — when trying to express the adjectival complement of integrity in its moral and ethical sense. ... To convey that one is of or marked by integrity, other adjectives may be used including upright and upstanding.

(Have a look at the [Google Fights](https://www.googlefight.com/integrous-vs-of+integrity.php) results)

So if you want to be understood, just use a synonym. This could be one of the (excellent) already suggested answers, or also [conscientious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conscientious),  [decent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decent), [honest](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/honest), [righteous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/righteous), [fair](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fair), [just](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just), or [genuine](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genuine).

Also, I'd like to highlight 'honorable':

> *1]* deserving of respect or high regard *2]* of great renown *3]* entitled to honor or respect *4]* consistent with a reputation that is not tarnished or sullied *5]* **characterized by integrity : guided by a keen sense of duty and ethical conduct** ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/honorable))

Answer (score 9):

**Righteous** is a bit stylized, but I regularly use it myself when I'm willing to be poetic/flowery.

> *adjective*
>
> 1. characterized by uprightness or morality: *a righteous observance of the law.*
> 2. morally right or justifiable: *righteous indignation.*
> 3. acting in an upright, moral way; virtuous: *a righteous and godly person.*
> 4. *Slang*. absolutely genuine or wonderful: *some righteous playing by a jazz great.*
>
> *noun*
>
> 5. the righteous, (*used with a plural verb*) righteous persons
>    collectively.

Partly I'm leaning on that slang usage which arises out of 1940's US jazz culture.

Example usage from a 2018 episode of the U.S. television show [*Elementary* (S6, E12)](https://youtu.be/ixdgHUqdIXI):

> U.S. MARSHAL STRIDER LINCOLN: You'd like fugitive apprehension. It's
> righteous work.

Definition at [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/righteous).

Etymology at [Etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/righteous).

Comment: Filling in the slot for the OP: "I was supervised by a righteous professor" ... that has an inappropriate ring of being overbearing (like 'self-righteous').

Comment: @Mitch: It may be a bit unusual, but personally I disagree; I would definitely say something like that. "Righteous" and "self-righteous" of course have very different meanings. ("not to be confused with...")

Comment: @Mitch In fact, one of its meanings is "With negative connotations: characterized by affected or hypocritical moral rectitude or superiority; self-righteous, sanctimonious." OED

Answer (score 4):

One colloquial word I've liked with this meaning is *stand-up* in "stand-up guy": (Oxford English Dictionary, [stand-up, n. and adj.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/188998)):

> 5. colloquial. Of a person: reliable, dependable, trustworthy. Frequently in stand-up guy. Occasionally also in extended use.
>
> 2013   A. Gibbons Raining Fire v. 65   Forget the tough exterior. Mick's a stand-up guy when you get to know him.

Usually that is said about someone who is provably dependable, that is, they have shown their trustworthiness. This usage is limited though. If you don't use *guy*, someone might think you're referring to, say, a stand-up comedian, or someone who does comedy on a stage in front of an audience. So saying this is clear:

> She wants her daughter to marry an intelligent, stand-up guy

However,

> (x) I was supervised by a stand-up professor

could require some rewording to ensure readers understand the professor is *honest* and not *funny*, e.g.,

> The professor who supervised me was a stand-up guy.

Answer (score 4):

If you would also be OK with a noun, I suggest:

> My supervising professor was a **mensch**. He always let me be the first
> author of my articles despite the common practice at the university.

**Mensch** (n.)

> A person of integrity and honor.
>
> Recent Web examples:
> ...
> *My Justin, who will always be the face of the Dodgers, was a **mensch**, a
> real human being, who along with his wife, Kourtney, did marvelously
> caring services for the entire Los Angeles community.*
>
> —Los Angeles Times, 23 Dec. 2022
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mensch)

> Mainly US informal
>
> A good, honest person.
>
> *I like him. He's a mensch.*
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/mensch)

> In American English
>
> A person, esp. a man, regarded as being honorable, decent, and
> responsible and having strength of character.
>
> *Webster’s New World College Dictionary, 4th Edition. Copyright © 2010 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt.*
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/mensch)

> A 'real man', the implication being of character and integrity rather
> than sexual or physical prowess.
> [Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/search/basic?q=mensch)

> A person (chiefly male) of stregth, integrity and honor or compassion
>
> **2004**, Alan Hollinghurst, *The Line of Beauty* ... Lionel Kessler,
> relaxing perhaps on a Louis Quinze day bed, garlanded all round with
> lines of beauty, seeing welcome proof that his clever maligned young
> friend was a **mensch**.
>
> **2008**, Dwight S. Huggins, *Into the Greenhouse Vol. VI: Dreams*, She was an Amerindian, and stout. She was a real **mensch**, […] a
> hard working person, who took pride in her job, which was to spray
> from an aerosol can a particular base.
> [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mensch)

> In German *Mensch* means "human being." In Yiddish...mensch continues
> to mean a human being but includes the connotation of an **especially
> decent, ethical human being.** This Yiddish usage of mensch has passed
> into American English (for example, "what a great guy his is—such a
> **mensch**!").
> [Aaron Gross; *The Question of the Animal and
> Religion*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Question_of_the_Animal_and_Religion/kTROBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=connotations%20of%20mensch&pg=PA206&printsec=frontcover) 2014

Comment: *I was supervised by a mensch professor.*? *She wants her daughter to marry an intelligent and mensch man*? Those don't work. (The OP asks for an adjective.)

Comment: This choice also conveys Nietzschian overtones that some authors may wish to avoid

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yes. I edited to offer a noun alternative.

Comment: @Kaji That is not the case for anyone familiar with how the word is used. It comes from the German through the Yiddish. For example there is a book title [*Be a Mensch: Unleash Your Power to Be Kind and Help Others*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Be_a_Mensch/trDKzQEACAAJ?hl=en)

Comment: @DjinTonic Honestly, I just assumed it was alt-right white supremacist slang that I hadn't heard before.

Comment: @DjinTonic I'm well aware of its origins, but a writer has to account for the fact that at least some of their audience may not be as familiar with etymology—especially when posting something publicly like on an internet forum (see Nick's comment for an example).  An awareness of potential issues lets authors make an informed decision on it.

Comment: I'm a native speaker, and I have never heard that word before.

Comment: @TinfoilHat the adjective form in Yiddish would be "menschlich" but I don't think that has entered the English language.

Comment: @ChrisMelville: I expect that's because you're UK-based. I think *mensch* is far more common in AmE because they have a higher proportion of *German* Jews who settled there on account of the Holocaust. A lot of them at around the same time, which encouraged the kind of "sociolinguistic continuity" that led to them retaining various German / Yiddish usages longer than would normally be the case in the UK.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is true--*Cambridge* labels it as "Mainly US," but also note the usage by Alan Hollinghurst, a British author (both above).

Comment: In the circumstances it's probably worth me explicitly pointing out that *on average*, immigrants to the UK tend to abandon their native culture and language quicker than immigrants to the US - with every assistance at both the political and personal level from the host nation (hence the French pronunciation of ***filet*** and ***herb*** in the US). Part and parcel of this is that UK-based Jews tend to avoid Yiddishisms more than their US-based counterparts, which quite naturally explains why Chris wasn't familiar with ***mensch***, even if he has an otherwise relatively wide vocabulary.

Answer (score 4):

How about simply **moral** ?

This evokes an image of someone whose main concern is doing things the right way. This also necessarily evokes a strictness and even boringness of outlook in the minds of more superficial people (and social challenge to the immoral, of course!) if morality is the only real concern.

In reality, morality has to balance several considerations - not least the law of unintended consequences from the actions based on a decision.

Answer (score 3):

How about ***respectable***?

> *I was supervised by a **respectable** professor. He always let me be the first author of my articles despite the common practice at the
> university.*
>
> *She wants her daughter to marry an intelligent and **respectable** man who is an XXX party member.*

> **respectable**, *adj.* and *n.*
> **A.** *adj.*
> **3. a.** Of a person: having a good or fair standing in society, either because of status or (esp. in later use) through being regarded
> as having a good character, a reputation for honesty or decency,
> etc.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com)
> (login required)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

This word **altruistic** comes to my mind.

> **altruistic** *adjective al·​tru·​is·​tic* ˌal-trü-ˈi-stik
> relating to or given to altruism:
>
> a: having or showing
> an unselfish concern for the welfare of others altruistic acts/motives
> a generous and altruistic person

Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/altruistic)

Comment: Altruistic relates more to virtuous/idealistic intention rather than the means to achieve it, which is more in the domain of moral character, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

***Incorruptible, honourable.***  It's generally more colourful to use a combination of words for that idea, incorruptible, steadfast, unflinching, unwavering virtue.

Comment: +1 for honorable.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at each of your examples.

> I was supervised by a **kind** professor. He always let me be
> the first author of my articles despite the common practice at the
> university.

I used the word **kind** in this example because the narrator is referring to an act of kindness.

> She wants her daughter to marry an intelligent and **trustworthy** man
> who is an XXX party member. But to make her wish physically
> fulfillable, she must remove one of these three requirements.

I used the word **trustworthy** in this example. For a person to be trustworthy, they need to have high integrity and strong moral principles.

> She wants her daughter to marry an intelligent and **conscientious**
> man who is an XXX party member. But to make her wish physically
> fulfillable, she must remove one of these three requirements.

We can also use the word **conscientious** in the second example. A person who is conscientious acts according to a strong and unerring conscience.

So my suggestions are **kind**, **trustworthy**, and **conscientious**.

Comment: +1 for conscientious. It's the best single answer for all of these uses.

Answer (score 2):

The word *zealous* can be applied to moral virtue.

> showing great energy or enthusiasm in pursuit of a cause or objective.

Answer (score 2):

One word would be "righteous". Sometimes comes on a bit strong, so best used in true cases.

Answer (score 2):

I was surprised only two people suggested `ethical` but not as their main answer? Seems a good fit to me although `honest` and `kind` works pretty well too.